# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. Problem in line 2

Tags: python, attributes, palindrome

```
x = input()
reverseuserinput = x[::-1]

if x == reverseuserinput:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

My code works in VS but when I submit it on leetcode it doesnt work and comes up with the error:
"'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'"

It says there is a problem in line 2 but I dont know how to solve.

Comment: Sounds like leetcode is using a **very old** version of python, where `input()` was a very different function than it is today.

Comment: Ok, ill just leave it.
Thankyou!

Comment: As John Gordon said - they use python 2.7. You can check it by running `import sys;
print(sys.version)`. If you want to understand the difference, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/4046632 And frankly, I would consider moving to different platform if I were you

Comment: Try `x = str(input())` in the first line

Comment: @sourin If the OP is using Python 2.7, they should not be using `input` in the first place; they should use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: just tried the code, it works perfectly fine on python `3.11`....

Comment: Thanks it works now, just realised I was on the wrong version of python for leetcode. Works fine on python 3. Thanks for all the replies.
I'm new to this 

Comment: @buran What better platform? LeetCode were the first site I know who already had Python 3.10, like a year ago already. I even occasionally abused it to test new Python functionality for SO answers.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I admit I am not familiar with leetcode. I just visited their homepage and checked the code editor widget there. I didn't know you can click playground and get more language choices, incl. python3. I dicovered it now. Anyway, I find it odd at best that they keep as the default version python2 and not python3.